# importing json array into hive

Tags: arrays, json, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to import the following json in hive

> [{"time":1521115600,"latitude":44.3959,"longitude":26.1025,"altitude":53,"pm1":21.70905,"pm25":16.5,"pm10":14.60085,"gas1":0,"gas2":0.12,"gas3":0,"gas4":0,"temperature":null,"pressure":0,"humidity":0,"noise":0},{"time":1521115659,"latitude":44.3959,"longitude":26.1025,"altitude":53,"pm1":24.34045,"pm25":18.5,"pm10":16.37065,"gas1":0,"gas2":0.08,"gas3":0,"gas4":0,"temperature":null,"pressure":0,"humidity":0,"noise":0},{"time":1521115720,"latitude":44.3959,"longitude":26.1025,"altitude":53,"pm1":23.6826,"pm25":18,"pm10":15.9282,"gas1":0,"gas2":0,"gas3":0,"gas4":0,"temperature":null,"pressure":0,"humidity":0,"noise":0},{"time":1521115779,"latitude":44.3959,"longitude":26.1025,"altitude":53,"pm1":25.65615,"pm25":19.5,"pm10":17.25555,"gas1":0,"gas2":0.04,"gas3":0,"gas4":0,"temperature":null,"pressure":0,"humidity":0,"noise":0}]

```
CREATE TABLE json_serde (
 s array<struct<time: timestamp, latitude: string, longitude: string, pm1: string>>)
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
     'mapping.value' = 'value'
 )
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
location '/user/hduser';
```

the import works but if i try

```
Select * from json_serde;
```

it will return from every document that is on hadoop/user/hduser only the first element per file.

there is a good documentation on working with json array??

Comment: added another approach to work with `json`. Kindly check.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue!!! crazy I know

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest you another approach to just load the whole `JSON` string into a column as `String` datatype into an external table. The only restriction is to define `LINES TERMINATED BY` properly. e.g. If you may have each json in one line, then you can create table as below:

e.g.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE json_data_table (
    json_data String
    )   
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION '/path/to/json';
```

Use [Hive `get_json_object`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-get_json_object) to extract individual columns. this commands support basic `xPath` like query to json string E.g.

If json_data column has below JSON string

```
{"store":
  {"fruit":\[{"weight":8,"type":"apple"},{"weight":9,"type":"pear"}],
   "bicycle":{"price":19.95,"color":"red"}
  },
 "email":"amy@only_for_json_udf_test.net",
 "owner":"amy"
}
```

The below query fetches

```
SELECT get_json_object(json_data, '$.owner') FROM json_data_table;
```

returns `amy`

In this way you could extract each `json` element as column from the table.

Comment: I've tried your solution @gyan but it did not worked.  SELECT get_json_object(json_data, '$') FROM json_data_table;
OK
NULL
NULL
NULL

Comment: I see 3 NULL in output. Are you trying the json in your query? Can you please make sure that your json is in one line, because in my solution I have mentioned `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` which mean each json line becomes a record?

Comment: I think there's little benefit to defining the rows just as strings rather than using the built in JSON serde and defining a struct over it

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of structs. What you pasted is only one line.

If you want to see all the elements, [you need to use inline](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-inline(arrayofstructs))

```
SELECT inline(s) FROM json_table;
```

Alternatively, you need to rewrite your files such that each object within that array is a single JSON object on its own line of the file

Also, I don't see a value field in your data, so I'm not sure what you're mapping in the serde properties

Comment: each line is [{"xx": value, "yy": value, ...}, {....}, {...}] and if i try to get for example from that array all xx;value from every element i can't

Answer (score 0):

The JSON that you provided is not correct. A JSON always starts with an opening curly brace `"{"` and ends with an ending curly brace `"}"`.
So, the first thing to look out here is that your JSON is wrong.

Your JSON should have been like the one below:

```
{"key":[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2""},{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]}
```

And, the second thing is you have declared the data-type of the "time" field as timestamp. But the data (1521115600) is in milliseconds. The timestamp data-type need data in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[.fffffffff].

So, your data should ideally be in the below format:

> {"myjson":[{"time":"1970-01-18
>   20:01:55","latitude":44.3959,"longitude":26.1025,"altitude":53,"pm1":21.70905,"pm25":16.5,"pm10":14.60085,"gas1":0,"gas2":0.12,"gas3":0,"gas4":0,"temperature":null,"pressure":0,"humidity":0,"noise":0},{"time":"1970-01-18
>   20:01:55","latitude":44.3959,"longitude":26.1025,"altitude":53,"pm1":24.34045,"pm25":18.5,"pm10":16.37065,"gas1":0,"gas2":0.08,"gas3":0,"gas4":0,"temperature":null,"pressure":0,"humidity":0,"noise":0},{"time":"1970-01-18
>   20:01:55","latitude":44.3959,"longitude":26.1025,"altitude":53,"pm1":23.6826,"pm25":18,"pm10":15.9282,"gas1":0,"gas2":0,"gas3":0,"gas4":0,"temperature":null,"pressure":0,"humidity":0,"noise":0},{"time":"1970-01-18
>   20:01:55","latitude":44.3959,"longitude":26.1025,"altitude":53,"pm1":25.65615,"pm25":19.5,"pm10":17.25555,"gas1":0,"gas2":0.04,"gas3":0,"gas4":0,"temperature":null,"pressure":0,"humidity":0,"noise":0}]}

Now, you can use query to select the records from the table.

```
hive> select * from json_serde;
OK
[{"time":"1970-01-18 20:01:55","latitude":"44.3959","longitude":"26.1025","pm1":"21.70905"},{"time":"1970-01-18 20:01:55","latitude":"44.3959","longitude":"26.1025","pm1":"24.34045"},{"time":"1970-01-18 20:01:55","latitude":"44.3959","longitude":"26.1025","pm1":"23.6826"},{"time":"1970-01-18 20:01:55","latitude":"44.3959","longitude":"26.1025","pm1":"25.65615"}]
Time taken: 0.069 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive>
```

If you want each value separately displayed in tabular format, you can use the below query.

```
select b.* from json_serde a lateral view outer inline (a.myjson) b;
```

The result of the above query would be like this:

```
+------------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+--+
|         b.time         | b.latitude  | b.longitude  |   b.pm1   |
+------------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+--+
| 1970-01-18 20:01:55.0  | 44.3959     | 26.1025      | 21.70905  |
| 1970-01-18 20:01:55.0  | 44.3959     | 26.1025      | 24.34045  |
| 1970-01-18 20:01:55.0  | 44.3959     | 26.1025      | 23.6826   |
| 1970-01-18 20:01:55.0  | 44.3959     | 26.1025      | 25.65615  |
+------------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+--+
```

Beautiful. Is n't it?

Happy Learning.

Comment: @craciuniulian, if you think my answer has solved your problem, you may upvote and mark it as answer so that it will be useful for others. Thanks.

Comment: "A JSON always starts with an opening curly brace "{" and ends with an ending curly brace "}" " - that's true for JSON objects... JSON arrays start with [ and end with ]. The Problem is not that "the JSON is not correct" but that the SerDe expects JSON objects not arrays

Answer (score 0):

If you can not use update your input file format you can directly import in spark and use it, once data is finalized write back to Hive table.

```
scala> val myjs = spark.read.format("json").option("path","file:///root/tmp/test5").load()
myjs: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [altitude: bigint, gas1: bigint ... 13 more fields]

scala> myjs.show()
+--------+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+---------+-----+--------+--------+----+--------+-----------+----------+
|altitude|gas1|gas2|gas3|gas4|humidity|latitude|longitude|noise|     pm1|    pm10|pm25|pressure|temperature|      time|
+--------+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+---------+-----+--------+--------+----+--------+-----------+----------+
|      53|   0|0.12|   0|   0|       0| 44.3959|  26.1025|    0|21.70905|14.60085|16.5|       0|       null|1521115600|
|      53|   0|0.08|   0|   0|       0| 44.3959|  26.1025|    0|24.34045|16.37065|18.5|       0|       null|1521115659|
|      53|   0| 0.0|   0|   0|       0| 44.3959|  26.1025|    0| 23.6826| 15.9282|18.0|       0|       null|1521115720|
|      53|   0|0.04|   0|   0|       0| 44.3959|  26.1025|    0|25.65615|17.25555|19.5|       0|       null|1521115779|
+--------+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+---------+-----+--------+--------+----+--------+-----------+----------+


scala> myjs.write.json("file:///root/tmp/test_output")
```

Alternatively you can directly hive table

```
   scala> myjs.createOrReplaceTempView("myjs")

    scala> spark.sql("select * from myjs").show()

    scala> spark.sql("create table tax.myjs_hive as select * from myjs")
```