# HiveSQL access JSON-array values

Tags: sql, arrays, json, hive, hiveql

I have a table in Hive, which is generated by reading from a Sequence File in my HDFS. Those sequence files are **json** and look like this:

```
{"Activity":"Started","CustomerName":"CustomerName3","DeviceID":"StationRoboter","OrderID":"CustomerOrderID3","DateTime":"2018-11-27T12:56:47Z+0100","Color":[{"Name":"red","Amount":1},{"Name":"green","Amount":1},{"Name":"blue","Amount":1}],"BrickTotalAmount":3}
```

They submit product part colours and the amount of them which are counted in one service process run.

Please notice the **json-array** in **color**

Therefore my code to create the table is:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE iotdata(
  activity              STRING,
  customername          STRING,
  deviceid              STRING,
  orderid               STRING,
  datetime              STRING,
  color                 ARRAY<MAP<String,String>>,
  bricktotalamount      STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE "org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe"
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/IoTData/scray-data-000-v0';
```

This works, and if I do a **select *** on that table it looks like this:

[image]

But my problem is, that I have to access the data inside the color column for analysis. For example, I want to calc all red values in the table.

So this leads to several opportunities and questions: how can I cast the amount string which is created to an integer?

How can I access the data in my color-column via select?

Or is there a possibility to change my table schema right at the beginning to get 4 extra columns for my 4 colours and 4 extra columns for the related colour amounts?

I also tried to read in the whole json as string to one column, and select the subcontent there, but this [importing json array into hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302628/importing-json-array-into-hive) leads me only to NULL values, propably because my json file is not 100% well-formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two steps.

**Create proper JSON table**

```
CREATE external TABLE temp.test_json (
  activity string,
  bricktotalamount int,
  color array<struct<amount:int, name:string>>,
  customername string,
  datetime string,
  deviceid string,
  orderid string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
location '/tmp/test_json/table'
```

[image]

**Explode the Table in Select Statement**

```
select activity, bricktotalamount, customername, datetime, deviceid, orderid, name, amount from temp.test_json
lateral view inline(color) c as amount,name
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Gaurang, this helped me much.
Thank you for your fast and understandable support! 

But i need to have the 4 colours and their amount in seperate columns. at the end it should look like: https://imgur.com/a/L4cq8LE - Can you please help me out again :-) ? Would be very nice.

Comment: What are you looking for `pivoting`. There is not inbuilt mechanism in `hive` however there are few third party libraries.  or if `orderid` is uniquer you can `groupby` it and then write `case` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The data inside of your array is definitely not a map for hive, you need to specify. I would  recommend redefine your table specifying the structure of the array's data like this

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE iotdata(
  activity              STRING,
  customername          STRING,
  deviceid              STRING,
  orderid               STRING,
  datetime              STRING,
  color ARRAY<STRUCT<NAME: STRING,AMOUNT:BIGINT>>
  bricktotalamount      STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE "org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe"
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/IoTData/scray-data-000-v0';
```

in that way you should be able to the structure it self

Comment: Thank you! This also works. I now have to see how i get the 4 colours in seperate columns, like i mentioned in the comments in the post above yours. Maybe you can help me here.