# Parse/ Query Key Value Pairs in SQL/ Hive

Tags: split, hive, key-value

I am trying to Parse/ Retrieve Data (Key Value Pairs) Value from a Column in Hive.

Did not manage to extract the "State Name" with a  Split Function and perhaps a Regular Expression.

```
**split(company.headquaters, "\...")[1] as State**
```

Please need some quick help or advice :) Best regards

company.headquarters:

```
{"city":"St. Paul","state":" Minnesota"}
{"city":"North Chicago","state":" Illinois"}
{"city":"Dublin","state":" Ireland"}
{"city":"Santa Monica","state":" California"}
```

Comment: Does `select get_json_object(company.headquarters,'$.state') as state from company;` work?

Comment: Also you can convert JSON strings to map and use map[key] : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57751960/2700344

Answer (score 1):

Could you pls try this -

```
select get_json_object(company.headquarters,'$.state') as state from company; work
```

Here is what i tested -
[image: Test Screenshot]